# Prove that A = B, regardless of what C is

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove which of the following statements imply **A = B**, regardless of what **C** is.

**A - C = B - C**

**A ∩ C = B ∩ C**

**A ⋃ C = B ⋃ C**

**A△C = B△C**

What might be wrong with the following approach?

if **C = ∅**:

**A - C = B - C** | → (**A - ∅ = A**; **B - ∅ = B**; so **A = B**);

**A ∩ C = B ∩ C** | → (**A ∩ ∅ = ∅**; **B ∩ ∅ = ∅**; so **∅ = ∅**);

**A ⋃ C = B ⋃ C** | → (**A ⋃ ∅ = A**; **B ⋃ ∅ = B**, so **A = B**);

**A △ C = B △ C** | → (**A - ∅**) ⋃ (**∅ - A**) = **A**; (**B - ∅**) ⋃ (**∅ - B**) = **B**, so **A=B**;

else:

**A - C = B - C** | → (Solve for "**A**" →  **A - C + C = B - C + C**; so **A = B**);

**A ∩ C = B ∩ C** | → If ⊄, then let ∈∖, and ={}, so **A ≠ B**;

**A ⋃ C = B ⋃ C** | → ={1}, ={2}, ={1,2,3,4}; ∪={1,2,3,4}; ∪={1,2,3,4}; so **A ≠ B**;

**A △ C = B △ C** | → 1+1=1+1; 1+1+1=1+1+1; 1=1; so **A=B**;

Comment: For the first, if $C= \emptyset^c$, then the equation is true regardless of what $A,B$ are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of looking at the question, suppose that $A\neq B$.  For each statement, can we find a $C$ such that the equality holds?

For the first, by letting $C= A\cup B$ we have $A\setminus C = B\setminus C = \emptyset$ despite the fact that $A\neq B$.

For the second, by letting $C=\emptyset$ we have $A\cap C = B\cap C=\emptyset$ despite the fact that $A\neq B$.

For the third, by letting $C=A\cup B$ we have $A\cup C=B\cup C$ despite the fact that $A\neq B$.

Only the fourth, we cannot find such an example of $C$, and this can be proven as in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

the fourth is the only one who implies this equality regardless of what $C$ is, but you need to prove it, and not just bring examples:
because of symmetry, its enough to prove that $A \subseteq B$:
let $a \in A$, then lets split to cases:
case 1: $a \notin C$, therefor $a \in A \triangle C$. because $A \triangle C = B \triangle C$, $a \in B \triangle C$, and because $a \notin C$ its implies that $a \in B$, therefor, $A\subseteq B$.
case 2: $a \in C$, therefor $a \notin A \triangle C$. because $A \triangle C = B \triangle C$, $a \notin B \triangle C$, and because $a \in C$ its implies that $a \in B$, therefor, $A\subseteq B$.
as you shown, all the others are depends in what $C$ is and can't imply that $A=B$